# sql view code doesn't select max

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql view:

```
SELECT
    `reports`.`date` AS `date`,
    `reports`.`book_title` AS `book_title`,
    max(
        `reports`.`royalty_type`
    ) AS `royalty_type`,
    max(
        `reports`.`avg_list_price`
    ) AS `avg_list_price`
FROM
    `reports`
GROUP BY
    `reports`.`date`,
    `reports`.`book_title`,
    `reports`.`marketplace`
```

As you can see it should select max from all `royalty_types` and from all
`avg_list_prices` in table and set the corresponding column values.
But it doesn't!

In my resulting sql table it looks like this:

```
DATE        BOOK_TITLE  Royalty_type  Avg_list_price
2016-07-20  name1       N/A           1,99
2016-07-21  name2       60%           2
2016-07-22  name3       60%           2
```

UPD: once again:
I try understand what this sql does cause it is not written by me. Let's say I need to rewrite this using another database and orm. 
 I see in code that it selects max of `royalty_type and avg_list_price`. but actually it doesn't select max.

I expected this code to produce this output:

```
   DATE        BOOK_TITLE  Royalty_type  Avg_list_price
    2016-07-20  name1       60%           2
    2016-07-21  name2       60%           2
    2016-07-22  name3       60%           2
```

Comment: What output do you want?  One row for each date?

Comment: it's "nice" feature of MySQL :) to get max per date/title you have to add `group by date, book_title`

Comment: @RomanPekar Assuming that is the desired output.  The current output does not imply this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I don't want any output. I try understand what this sql does cause it is not written by me. And I try to understand what it should do I see in code that it selects max, but actually it doesn't select max, so that was my question

Comment: @RomanPekar - I've updated code - you mean that if there is no `group by royalty_type, avg_list_price` - this code will not select maximum?

Comment: @user2950593 This question is really out of context.  You should first decide what output you want, then worry about which query will generate that output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I don't think so. Let's say I have to replicate this cpde for other database like mongo db and and other technology rails. So I need to understand what it does

Comment: We have to take your word for it that this query doesn't produce the correct output. Since we don't know the original data we cannot verify that. The query seems fine. As such I will have to assume the output is correct, and your interpretation of it isn't.

Comment: What are the types of the columns avg_list_price, and royalty_type as defined in your database ?

Comment: @AbdullahDibas royalty_type - varchar, avg_list_price - decimal

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I didn't say it is incorrect. It is correct and output is correct. But why they use select max from column royalty_type - if it doesn't selects max?

Comment: it most certainly does select max, just not the way you imagine it to. it only selects the max within the group (defined by `group by`). also, the `max` of a `varchar` column can be somewhat unexpected, unless you understand character encoding and collation, which I assume you don't. provide sample data please, or we're all just playing the guessing game here.

Answer (score 0):

The query that you have written will calculate the `max()` within each group specified by the `group by`.  If you want the overall `max()`, then you need a different approach:

```
SELECT r.*, m.*
FROM reports r CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT max(r.royalty_type) as royalty_type,
             max(r.avg_list_price) as avg_list_price
      FROM reports
     ) m;
```

Comment: can you tell me more? how it selects max within a group? it groups by date, then groups by `book_title`, then groups by  `marketplace` and selects max within one day, one `book_title` and one `marketplace`?

Comment: for `group by` it doesn't matter in which order you group ... a group consists of every record, that has the same combination of (marketplace,book_title,date) - for your specific case